# Application memory usage tracking

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

We have C#.Net windows application and i need to know how to get the memory consumption details of my application. I already tried `System.Diagnostics.Process` to get the current process memory information. I need to know how many objects are in memory and also memory consumption details for each objects.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about **Garbage collector** and take a look at this article [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.aspx)
The article  shows the members of GC  that can show you how to do a few things, how to get the total amount of allocated memory , how many times the GC has collected.

Other than that you'll have to probably use a profiler as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers).

You can also write your own profiler.[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15410/Creating-a-Custom-NET-Profiler) could be of help

Comment: ya i already used CLR profiler, ANTS profiler to track the memory allocation details. But i need the source code to get the objects and its memory allocation details.

Comment: @Siva please take a look at my updated answer